# Why does zeus keep crashing on OSX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, zeus

I have foreman with a Rails 4.2 app.

The Procfile.development file is:

```
zeus: echo "Starting Zeus..." && zeus start &> /dev/null
web: sleep 1 && zeus s
redis: redis-server
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq
```

the command I use to start the Rails app is `bundle exec foreman start -f Procfile.development` and see the crash report:

````
10:40:27 zeus.1    | started with pid 70377
10:40:27 web.1     | started with pid 70378
10:40:27 redis.1   | started with pid 70379
10:40:27 sidekiq.1 | started with pid 70381
10:40:27 zeus.1    | Starting Zeus...
10:40:27 redis.1   | 70379:C 01 Apr 10:40:27.425 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
10:40:27 redis.1   | 70379:M 01 Apr 10:40:27.426 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
10:40:27 redis.1   |                 _._                                                  
10:40:27 redis.1   |            _.-``__ ''-._                                             
10:40:27 redis.1   |       _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.0.5 (00000000/0) 64 bit
10:40:27 redis.1   |   .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._                                   
10:40:27 redis.1   |  (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
10:40:27 redis.1   |  |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
10:40:27 redis.1   |  |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 70379
10:40:27 redis.1   |   `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'                                   
10:40:27 redis.1   |  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
10:40:27 redis.1   |  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io        
10:40:27 redis.1   |   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
10:40:27 redis.1   |  |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|                                  
10:40:27 redis.1   |  |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |                                  
10:40:27 redis.1   |   `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'                                   
10:40:27 redis.1   |       `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'                                       
10:40:27 redis.1   |           `-._        _.-'                                           
10:40:27 redis.1   |               `-.__.-'                                               
10:40:27 redis.1   | 
10:40:27 redis.1   | 70379:M 01 Apr 10:40:27.427 # Server started, Redis version 3.0.5
10:40:27 redis.1   | 70379:M 01 Apr 10:40:27.427 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
10:40:27 redis.1   | 70379:M 01 Apr 10:40:27.427 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
10:40:27 zeus.1    | exited with code 1
10:40:27 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
10:40:27 redis.1   | 70379:signal-handler (1459532427) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
10:40:27 web.1     | terminated by SIGTERM
10:40:27 sidekiq.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
10:40:28 redis.1   | 70379:M 01 Apr 10:40:28.047 # User requested shutdown...
10:40:28 redis.1   | 70379:M 01 Apr 10:40:28.047 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
10:40:28 redis.1   | 70379:M 01 Apr 10:40:28.049 * DB saved on disk
10:40:28 redis.1   | 70379:M 01 Apr 10:40:28.049 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
10:40:28 redis.1   | exited with code 0
````

Previously I solved this problem by doing `pkill -f zeus` and killing a bunch of ghost zeus processes.  It worked before, but it is not now.  I think what caused the current problem is that I had to reboot my laptop running OSX when it froze.  Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I kept running into these issues as well and eventually switched to Spring. I know this doesn't answer your question, but worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyE, because this app is at work, I'd have to run the idea by multiple people.